# Ubuntu EFI is not removing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I recently tried to dual boot windows with ubuntu but I changed my mind and deleted the disk partition where ubuntu was installed. Now, when I use `bcdedit /enum firmware`, I still see the EFI Ubuntu boot manager, even after using `bcdedit /delete {id}`. Please help

[Image: What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtiVQ.png)

Comment: Just delete the ubuntu entry in your UEFI settings/BIOS boot order.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on